# how to increment epoch time by 5 minutes in Scala or Java

Tags: java, scala, datetime

```
val df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz")

var date1 = new Date()

println(date1.getTime)
```

Result:
`1407309964324`

how can i increment it by 5 minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Calendar class's `add` method to add specify time of date from seconds, minute, hours, etc. in Calendar's constant.

**sample:**

```
    Date date1 = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date1);
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5); //adds five minute to the calendar's date
    System.out.println(date1.getTime()); //current time
    System.out.println(c.getTime().getTime()); //current time + 5 minutes
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, 5 minutes is always 300,000 milliseconds, so:

```
long millis = date1.getTime();
millis += 300000;
Date date2 = new Date(millis);
```

Or perhaps more readably:

```
long millis = date1.getTime();
millis += TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMilliseconds(5);
Date date2 = new Date(millis);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll just note that `Date` and `Calendar` are generally considered very badly designed. Java 8 has a new date/time library (for previous Java versions, use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), which the Java 8 library was based on, or http://www.threeten.org/), using which you'd write:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

...
OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.now();
OffsetDateTime dt1 = dt.plusMinutes(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

In java you can use the `Calendar`to do it:

```
Date date1 = new Date();
Calendar c= new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(date1);
c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
date1 = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java8, you can increment 5 minutes to your supplied `Date` value using the following scala code:

```
// because the supplied Date in your question uses this Date structure:
import java.util.Date

import java.time.Instant
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId

// supplied date from your question
val date1 = new Date()

// convert to LocalDateTime
val ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date1.getTime), ZoneId.systemDefault)

 // add five minutes
val incrementedBy5 = ldt.plusMinutes(5)

// convert to Long
val asLongInt: Long = incrementedBy5.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond
```

or in a single line:

```
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date1.getTime), ZoneId.systemDefault).plusMinutes(5).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond
```